# Is this map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$
f(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $x\leq 0$,} \\
 x & \text{if $x > 0$.}
  \end{cases}
$$
Then let $(a,b)$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$,
$$
f^{-1}(a,b) = 
  \begin{cases}
    \emptyset   &\text{if $b\leq 0$,} \\
 (-\infty,b) &\text{if $a<0<b$,} \\
    (a,b)  &\text{if $0<a$.} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
This shows that $f(x)$ is continuous, right? Something seems off about this function...

Comment: Last case should be $0\leq a$ instead of $0<a$, but otherwise everything is fine.

Comment: The only thing that's "off" about it is that it's not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Great! I think this shows then that if the image of a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is neither open nor closed, then it has the form $(a,b]$ where $-\infty\leq a<b<\infty$ or $[a,b)$ or $-\infty< a<b\leq\infty$ by a connectedness argument and noticing any interval two intervals $(a,b]$, $(c,d]$ or $[a,b)$, $[c,d)$ of the form above are homeomorphic.

Comment: On your last comment: almost. If $a=-\infty$ then $(a,b]$ is closed (and you preassumed that the image would not be closed), and if $b=\infty$ then $[a,b)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a characterization of a continuous map, i.e. the theorem that a map is continuous iff the preimage of every set open in the codomain is open in the domain under the map; your argument is correct to me.

If for now you have not already gotten used to the approach, you may consider the limiting characterization, which may be more familiar to you. The map $f$ restricted to $]-\infty, 0[$ is constant, so it is continuous; the map $f$ restricted to $]0,+\infty[$ is identity, so it is continuous. Clearly we have $\lim_{x \to 0-}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x) = 0$, so $f$ is continuous at $0$ too; therefore, the map $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.